# How to populate a column with a count of numbers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am converting to an integer primary key and am having trouble seeding the new column data with a count of integer numbers.

Given an existing table:

```
create table t1 (
  Id uniqueidentifier, 
  NewId int,
  Data nvarchar(100)
)
```

How would I update existing rows with a count of numbers from 1 to the # of rows in the result set?

So:

```
|id      |NewId       |Data
-------------------------------
|ABC     |null        |first
|DEF     |null        |second
|GHI     |null        |third
```

Would become:

```
|id      |NewId    |Data
----------------------------
|ABC     |1        |first
|DEF     |2        |second
|GHI     |3        |third
```

This is for a migration to using a hilo primary key with nhibernate, which is needed to reduce database round trips with between my application and database tiers, so IDENTITY is not an option for me.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Does the sequence ever reset?

Comment: SQL Server 2008.  Once I have the data populated, I'll use a different method for managing the primary key.  I just need to populate the existing data once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a windowing function like `row_number`:

```
update t
set NewId = sub.rn
from YourTable t
join (
    select
        id
    ,   row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from YourTable
) sub on sub.id = t.id
```

Comment: I tried this and it says I must declare @t.  Is this missing from the example?

Comment: @Michael: Whoops, @t should be YourTable. Edited in answer

Answer (score 2):

Use RowNumber(), it is great for things like this:

```
;WITH SequencedData AS
(
  SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) Sequence 
  FROM [YourTable]
)
UPDATE t
SET NewId = sd.Sequence
FROM [YourTable] t
JOIN SequencedData sd
  ON sd.Id = t.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a variable and increment it by 1 for every row being updated.

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 

UPDATE TableName 
SET @id = ColumnName = @id + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure how efficient it is, but this works - see the update command near the bottom

```
create table t1 (Id uniqueidentifier, 
                 NewId int,
                 Data nvarchar(100))
create index idx_t1 on t1(data)

insert into t1 values (newid(), null, 'B')
insert into t1 values (newid(), null, 'A')
insert into t1 values (newid(), null, 'F')
insert into t1 values (newid(), null, 'C')
insert into t1 values (newid(), null, 'E')

update t1
   set [newid]=(select count(*) from t1 as temp where temp.data <= t12.data)
from t1 as t12

select * from t1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @CurrentRow INT
SET @CurrentRow = 1

DECLARE SetIDCursor INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT  Id
    FROM t1
    ORDER BY Id
    FOR READ ONLY

OPEN SetIDCursor

WHILE (0=0)
   BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM SetIDCursor
    INTO    @Id

    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) BREAK

    UPDATE t1
    SET NewID = @CurrentRow
    WHERE Id = @Id

    SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1
   END

CLOSE SetIDCursor
DEALLOCATE SetIDCursor
```

Comment: This example worked and took 30 seconds.  The one I accepted took 1 second, so I marked that as answered.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cursors really should be a last resort

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do this yourself, why not just add the column as identity.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
    ADD NewId INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

This will take care of it for you.

Comment: The reason why is I'm not going to be using the IDENTITY functionality.  Instead I'll be using a hilo algorithm through nhibernate to avoid database round trips on inserts.

Comment: In this case a solution using Row_NUMBER might be the best way to go.

Comment: You can remove the IDENTITY after updating the data, so this does serve exactly the same function as Row_Number and I have used it in the past for the same purpose.